# What do we know about the relation of shape to size in asteroids?

Tags: asteroids

Have enough good measurements been made of small asteroids to gather interesting statistics about roundness?  Perhaps a scatter chart of each body's greatest and least diameter?

Comment: I can't really answer this, but perhaps it might be helpful to ask the team around the Asteroids@home (http://asteroidsathome.net) project since this should have been a side product of their computations. Their data is published in the DAMIT database at https://astro.troja.mff.cuni.cz/projects/damit/, which I have no experience with.